# Python for loop print statement not working at end

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I try to print a variable defined inside a function after a for loop but it is not getting printed. Infact i tried printing just 'HI' after the for loop but it is not being printed

```
def find_sum_delay(slack):
    global temp_list
    total_delay = 0

    unique_temp_list = list(unique_everseen(temp_list))


    #print(unique_temp_list)

    for cell in unique_temp_list:
        if cell.startswith('BUFH_'):
            print(temp_list.count(cell),cell, bufh_dict_celltype[cell])
            print(temp_list.count(cell) *  bufh_dict_celltype[cell])
            total_delay = total_delay + (temp_list.count(cell) *  bufh_dict_celltype[cell])
        print(total_delay)

    print('hi')
```

For the above code, total_delay is being printed but at end of for loop hi is not being printed all of a sudden. it worked properly just a few hours ago

Comment: can you show us your output?

Comment: How is the function called? Your for-loop might raise an exception (interrupting the execution) which is swallowed by the caller, eg. `try: find_sum_delay(slack) except Exception: pass`.